# Milking Cows, Solution Explanation

Tags: c++, algorithm, bit, bitset

I practicing C++ solving some exercises, but after the whole day, I couldn't solve on of them. So, I searched through the web and found a short solution, but, I can't understand it.

The Exercise:
http://jeremiahflaga.blogspot.com/2011/09/milking-cows-programming-problem-from.html

The Solution
https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=13658&lngWId=3

I'm interested because I want to learn to solve problems using binary data, like this exercise, all the data is stored inside a bitset.

So, It would be nice is someone can explain the solution to me.

Comment: Maybe look up "interval scheduling"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all the solution does is populate and then read a bitset.

there is an entry in the bitset for every second, and bits are set to 1 whenever someone is milking a cow (they are set while reading the input in the `for(int j = begin + 1; j <= end; j++)` loop).

then, once all input is read, and all appropriate bits are set, the bitset is scanned to count the longest sequences of 0s and 1s (the switch from 0 to 1 or vice-versa is detected by `if(a[i] != toggler)` where `toggler` is the previous bit value).

if you cannot see the above, i'd suggest copying the code into an ide or editor and reformatting it so that it is indented correctly.

it's not a great solution.  maybe it's the right way to win the competition, but it's not the kind of code most people would write in normal conditions as it's very wasteful of memory.  typically for this kind of problem in "real life" you would manage the intervals using (begin, end) pairs, merging overlapping intervals.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand how it works and why you say that it's wasteful of memory. I tried to solve the problem using the approach you recommend ( pairs of start-end, and merging overlaping ones), using vector class. Maybe implementing an ordered list will be easier. Thanks!

Comment: merging intervals is quite tricky.  it's not "hard" conceptually, but it's easy to make mistakes, especially in a language like c++ if you're not used to it.  you probably had some bugs in the details - if you separate that part of the code out and then write a lot of tests (add one pair, check, add another that doesn't overlap, check, repeat with an overlap on one side only, etc etc etc you would probably find the bugs and get it to work).